# What is meant by a primitive data type?

Tags: data-types

My understanding of a primitive datatype is that

> It is a datatype provided by a language implicitly (Others are user defined classes)

So different languages have different sets of datatypes which are considered primitive for that particular language. Is that right?

And what is the difference between a "basic datatype" and "built-in datatype". Wikipedia says a primitive datatype is either of the two.

**PS - Why is "string" type considered as a primitive type in SNOBOL4 and not in Java ?**

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It kind of depends on the language.

For example, in languages like C and C++, you have a number of built-in scalar types - `int`, `float`, `double`, `char`, etc.  These are "primitive" in the sense that they cannot be decomposed into simpler components.  From these basic types you can define new types - pointer types, array types, struct types, union types, etc.

Then you have a language like old-school Lisp, where everything is either an *atom* or a *list*.  Again, by the above definition, an atom is "primitive" in the sense that it cannot be decomposed into something simpler.

*Edit*

As far as I'm concerned, the terms "primitive", "basic", and "built-in" are pretty much interchangeable.  If you want to get *really* pedantic, though, you can distinguish between types that are "built-in" (those explicitly provided by the language definition) and types derived from the built-in types that are still "primitive" or "basic" in that they cannot be decomposed into simpler elements.  C's `typedef` facility allows you to create new type names for existing types.  Ada allows you to create new scalar types that have constraints on them.  For example, you can derive a Latitude type from the built-in floating type, with the constraint that it can't take on values outside the range [-90.0, 90.0].  It's still a primitive or basic type in that it cannot be broken down into any simpler components, but since it's user-defined, it's not considered a "built-in" type.

Again, these concepts are a little fuzzy, and it really depends on context.  For example, the notion of a "built-in" type is meaningless for a typeless language like BLISS.

Comment: whats the difference between basic and built in datatypes ?

Comment: Is "string" a primitive datatype in Java ?? (I have seen delnan's comment to Jesper's answer) . I want to know your opinion , because in one of your comments you said "whether or not primitive type depends on whom you ask" .

Comment: @Appy - see edit.

Comment: @Appy - I agree with Jesper and delnan.  In Java, I wouldn't consider `String` to be a primitive type, although it is a built-in type (provided by the language definition).  Again, the concept itself is fuzzy.

Comment: :) Even I used to take these as rather interchangeable terms .. but "programming languages principles" appears to be formal field of study and is forcing me to look at these things the way I am !

Comment: whatever datatype a language provides in its definition is a"built-in" . Every "built-in" need not be "primitive" and vice versa .. "primitive" and "basic" mean same !! Please say if its right/wrong ?

Comment: @Appy: AFAIC they mean the same thing, but I don't work in a formal, academic setting.  I'm neither a language designer nor a compiler implementor.  I'm just a code monkey working in the industry, and I don't have to be that precise with my terminology.  So I may very well be wrong as far as formal defitions are concerned.

Comment: Ok Thanks .. :) Extending our discussion , can you tell me why is "string" type considered as "primitive" in SNOBOL4 but not in Java ?

Comment: @Appy: Not a clue.  I have no experience with SNOBOL.

Comment: @Appy String in Java isn't primitive because it is a compound type. If you look at String class source code (src.zip in JDK folder) you will see, that internally String is represented as an array of characters. So you can decompose String into individual characters. You can't decompose character into smaller values which makes `char` a primitive type and `String` a compound type.

Comment: I consider all pointers in C/C++ primitate data types (even `MyClass *`). Constructing a type at a type level is very different than constructing what the type represents. Pointer semantics are fixed by the language, built-in, and cannot be constructed from other types via language constructs.

Comment: @Jacek . Thats clear enough :) But then why is it considered a primitive type in SNOBOL4 ?

Comment: @JacekPrucia . So if I delete the src.zip file , the string type wont be supported in my Java ?? I think there is no external file like that (in SNOBOL4) which gives the "string" type a built-in functionality .. I am not that familiar with SNOBOL4 . And I think that is the reason (src.zip file) Java specification did not include "string" type in their primitive types . Because it is not '_completely_' built-in ! Please correct if I am wrong :)

Comment: @Appy you can delete src.zip file and it wont have effect on inner workings of Java. The file is simply for the curious to better understand how basic classes are built. No idea about SNOBOL4 but it appears from quick googling that string is primitive type there. There is no char type in SNOBOL4, you can only have string of length 1 to represent it. The lack of ability to decompose SNOBOL4 string to something "smaller" makes this type primitive.

Comment: @JacekPrucia Ohh .. Thanks :) But in the case of SNOBOL4 , I dont think that is the reason which makes it (string type) as a primitive type . I think it's a primitive type because it is built-in ! I can be wrong offcourse ! Anyway in SNOBOL4 , a string is basic as well as built-in then ? Isnt it ? (See my answer to this question) .

Comment: @Appy You are missing the point. SNOBOL4 strings can't be decomposed. Java strings can. Thats the difference. Both are built in but only SNOBOL4 strings are primitive.

Comment: @JohnBode Why are primitive types faster to work with? Just simply due to the fact they don't have the extra wrapping non-primitives do? I'm trying to figure out the difference between primitives and non-primitives...as in are primitives built into the CPU or something?

Comment: From Wikipedia: "Depending on the language and its implementation, primitive data types may or may not have a one-to-one correspondence with objects in the computer's memory. However, one usually expects operations on basic primitive data types to be the fastest language constructs there are." --- So this 1-to-1 correspondence is the root cause of it being faster, whereas with objects, it isn't 1-to-1. Am I correct?

Answer (score 20):

From the **Java** perspective:

In Java, there is a very clear distinction between primitive and non-primitive types.

A variable of a primitive type directly contains the value of that type (in other words, they are *value types*).

A variable of a non-primitive type doesn't contain the value directly; instead, it is a *reference* (similar to a pointer) to an object. (It is not possible in Java to create user-defined value types).

Java has eight primitive types: `byte`, `short`, `int`, `long`, `char`, `boolean`, `float` and `double`. Anything else is a non-primitive type.

Comment: So String datatype is non-primitive in Java. In every Java main() program we write "public static void main(String args[])". Why? Why we always have to pass a String argument in main? Also we never need to import the String type in Java the way we include it in C/C++(eg. #include<string> or using std::string). Please explain.

Comment: @Maxood `String` *does* have special status in the language (it gets literals, it's in the signature of `main`, there's interning which I presume is explicitly allowed by the JLS, it's available automagically, etc.) but it isn't a *primitive* data type. One might call it *built-in*.

Comment: @Jesper Why are primitive types faster to work with? Just simply due to the fact they don't have the extra wrapping non-primitives do? I'm trying to figure out the difference between primitives and non-primitives...as in are primitives built into the CPU or something?

Comment: From Wikipedia: "Depending on the language and its implementation, primitive data types may or may not have a one-to-one correspondence with objects in the computer's memory. However, one usually expects operations on basic primitive data types to be the fastest language constructs there are." --- So this 1-to-1 correspondence is the root cause of it being faster, whereas with objects, it isn't 1-to-1. Am I correct?

Comment: @Abdul yes, primitives are just "direct values" while non-primitive types are really pointers to a value, so there is a level of indirection - every time the value needs to be accessed, it has to be done through this extra level of indirection.

Comment: @Jesper Forgive my ignorance, but what does "direct values" exactly mean? Do these primitive, smallest unit of data type, exist in the CPU? Or do they reside in whatever tool compiles/interprets the code e.g. JVM? (That would go hand in hand with Jörg W Mittag's answer below, which states primitives are only those that the language specified)

Comment: @Jesper Like for example, I believe arrays in C are primitive, whereas in Java they are not. So, theoretically, a language can choose any type to be primitive, but then having too many data types to be primitive is analogous to loading all the components of a library, when you won't use them all. I understand from a conceptual POV what primitives are (meaning smallest unit), and I understand why they're faster (cus they aren't wrapped), but I'm failing to understand under-the-hood

Comment: My old thinking was that CPUs (since they are the brain of computers) provide `x` number of primitive types, i.e. `int` `double` `float` etc. and the primitives in languages just map to those. So that is what primitive meant (to me back then)

Comment: @Abdul don't make it too complicated. The CPU has a number of registers, that can contain different kinds of primitive values (for example a 32-bit or 64-bit integer or a single or double precision floating point number) and the CPU has instructions implemented in hardware to do operations on the values in the registers. Your last remark is essentially correct.

Answer (score 9):

A primitive is a basic data type that's not built out of other data types.  It can only represent one single value.  All primitives are built-in data types by necessity, (the compiler has to know about them,) but not all built-in data types are primitives.

In some languages, the compiler has built-in knowledge of certain types that are built out of other things, because it has to be able to treat them in a special way.  Examples would be the Variant in Delphi and Visual Basic (and the Boo equivalent, "Duck") and the base object class in most OO languages.

Comment: Thanks :) Your answer is very informative , but I am unable to understand clearly . CAn you give some examples (probably with C/C++/Java) .

Comment: @Mason Wheeler This is where we use the term loose typing and strong typing. As i have heard people saying that VB is a loosely typed language while Java is a strongly typed one. Please confirm.

Comment: @Appy C++ ships with classes for strings, vectors, and maps.  These are built-in they come with the language, are in the language definition etc.  However they are written in C++ they come from the standard library.  You could write your own that behaves identically.  Compare this to an int or a char. You can't define your own char in C++.  You could overload every operator on a class and get something that behaves similarly but not identically.  This is a primitive.  Basically something defined in a language that is not implementable in that language.

Answer (score 5):

> Why is "string" type considered as a primitive type in SNOBOL4 and not in Java ?

Because the Java Language Specification very clearly specifies what the word "primitive" means in the context of Java, and Java's `String` doesn't conform to this specification, whereas the SNOBOL4 Language Specification defines what "primitive" means in the context of SNOBOL4 and SNOBOL4's string conforms to that specification.

There's really nothing more to it. The specification of the respective language defines what certain words mean and something either fits that description or it doesn't. For example, the C Language Specification defines the meaning of the word "function" to be something which is very clearly *not* what the word "function" usually means, but that's the way the word is used inside the C community.

Comment: @Mittag Based on your answer , I googled some phrases and came across a very nice [link](http://users.sdsc.edu/~ludaesch/CSE130/ln2.html) which almost clears all the doubts on this particular topic :) .

Answer (score 0):

A 'primitive' data type means that you have a value stored in memory--this value has no methods or internal structure. A primitive can only be operated on by external operations.

In Java, primitives are numbers (int, long, etc.) and char. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

If your value has structure (I'm thinking of struts here) then it is not a primitive. If it has methods (an object or class) it is not a primitive.

Comment: C#'s primitive `int` data type *does* have methods...

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: `var myString = 3.ToString();` (see [Int32.ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wch342y.aspx)). Note that `int` in C# is a *synonym* for `Int32`, i.e., `Int32` *is* a primitive type (unlike Java, where `Integer` is different from `int`). Thus, `3.ToString()` in C# does *not* involve boxing!

Comment: That's very interesting; the link you provided indicates that 'int' is really an object of the class 'Int32' (or maybe a combination of the primitive and a wrapper class), so by the definition I put: 'int' is not a primitive. :)

Comment: Then there are no primitive classes in C#, since *all* data types have a `ToString()` method. ;-)

Comment: Wikipedia says that all Types inherit from System.object due to the Common Type System (CTS), so I guess that would be the case. I didn't know anything about c# before your comment--I had heard that it was like Java, but this aspect is more like Python.

Comment: I really don't get where this "C# is like Java" myth comes from. C# was designed by the designer of Borland Pascal and a big fan of Modula-2, and it is in fact much closer to "Modula-2 + objects" than Java's "Objective-C - C + types".

Comment: Console.WriteLine(typeof(int).IsPrimitive); //true
Console.WriteLine(typeof(string).IsPrimitive); // false  So one wonders how C# defines primitives, given that int, which we've seen in C# has methods, is called primitive.

Comment: @JörgWMittag in herbert schildt's book on C# he says Java is descended from C++, and C# is descended from C++.  So Java and C# are like cousins, they share a common ancestry.

Comment: @Heinzi  No. C# calls int a primitive. And don't try to make a technical comment with a wink at the end, it creates confusion. And see my comment. BTW, the C# 5 reference only uses the word primitive twice and once is in inverted commas. It uses the term "simple type" more. I can't comment much on how it defines primitives, i'm new to it. We know in Java primitives have no methods.

Comment: @barlop: My comment starts with "Then...", so please read it in context: Josh said that *by his definition*, C#'s `int` is not a primitive type, and I replied that, *in that case* ("then"), *none* of C#'s types were primitive, since none meets *his definition of primitive*.

Comment: ...and the wink illustrates the (obvious) implication that his definition of a primitive type is not particularly in the context of C#.

Comment: @barlop: Java is *not* descended from C++. If Herbert Schildt can't even get such a simple fact straight, I'm not sure I would trust the rest of the book either. Patrick Naughton, original designer of Java, was a huge Objective-C fan. In fact, he had already given notice to work on Objective-C at NeXT, when Scott McNealy convinced him to stay at Sun and design a new language. James Gosling, the other original designer, was very familiar with Smalltalk (direct ancestor of Objective-C) and Lisp (inspiration for Smalltalk). Later on, several members of the Objective-C design team moved to Sun.

Comment: See [Java Was Strongly Influenced by Objective-C … and *not* C++ …](http://cs.gmu.edu/~sean/stuff/java-objc.html). C++ has multiple inheritance, Java doesn't. Java has interfaces, C++ doesn't. Java is pointer-safe, memory-safe and type-safe, C++ is neither. Java has automatic memory management, C++ manual. Java methods are always virtual, C++ only by choice. C++ has free functions, Java has only methods. Java is highly reflective, C++ only has RTTI, and that's optional. Java has only late binding, dynamic dispatch, dynamic linking, dynamic loading, C++ favors static.

Comment: @JörgWMittag What about syntax - where does Java get its syntax from?  (I have some familiarity with java and c# and not the others), I just looked at a "hello world" in objective c, one that looks a bit like it included defining a class, it doesn't even say class blah(like java n C#).And here  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Hello_world_program_examples I looked up (not case sensitive) public static void main   and it came up in java and c# and no others.(and a search suggested even C++ doesn't have that)suggesting then that (dare I say it) C# got the allowance for that syntax from Java

Answer (score 0):

I came across some information and felt it would aid the other answers . So want to share it -

Wikipedia says -

**In computer science, primitive data type is either of the following:**

***A basic type* is a data type provided by a programming language as a basic building block. Most languages allow more complicated composite types to be recursively constructed starting from basic types.

*A built-in type* is a data type for which the programming language provides built-in support.**

*In most programming languages, all basic data types are built-in. In addition, many languages also provide a set of composite data types("string" type in Java).*

I would like to say it this way -
A basic datatype is a datatype which cannot be further broken down ("string" type can be made from "char", but char cannot be 'broken down' into any datatype (In most of Programming languages) . So it is basic datatype)

**String type , in SNOBOL4 is considered primitive .Though I dont know the exact reason why . It's both basic as well as built-in in SNOBOL4 .**

**Java specification clearly mentions the list of datatypes it considers to be primitive type . Because the string type is not in their [specification](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~sedwards/papers/gosling2000java.pdf) , it's not a primitive datatype in Java , inspite of being a built-in type .**

Answer (score -2):

Primitives are fundamental data types provided by the language itself. Example in C language are int, float, char data types. It is provided as fundamental part of the language.

Non primitives are user defined variables or objects. For example you can define an object which store data or you can use struct in C to define you own variables. These are not primitive because you had to define them first in order to used them.

> Examples: Employee, Student,
>   a_very_large_number_that_you_defined_yourself

**Edit with more explanation and addressing the comment**
I think of primitive as variables that came originally with the language and not variables like String in C++ which you have to declare using the New keyword. That makes it an object so a String would not be a primitive.

Answer you comment: It probably has to do with implementation of the variable. If it was part of language core, it is primitive. If not it is not. Example is String in C++. This is not a core variable and is declared using New keyword. So it is not primitive.

Comment: Thanks for the answer . Does classification of a datatype as "primitive" depend on the implementation ? Like in C/C++ we store strings as char arrays .But we need to explicitly define them . So if some other language has the same implementation to store a string but provides it implicitly , will the datatype "string" be a primitive in that particular language ?

Comment: @Appy - possibly.  C doesn't provide a `string` data type as such; strings are represented as aggregates of the primitive type `char`.  C++ introduced a proper `string` data type, but whether or not it's a "primitive" type itself depends on whom you ask.  Personally, I would not classify it as such.  However, I would classify an old-school BASIC string type as a primitive type, for reasons that are probably completely arbitrary.

Comment: Addressed your comment int the question itself. Plz see edit.

Comment: strings in C++ do not need to be created with new

Comment: @jk I was out of touch with C++. You are right. Will fix the ans.

Answer (score -2):

For better understanding the concept of primitive types and user-defined datatypes all that the other answers lacks is the concept of `compiler`.

If you understand the concept of [lexemes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) getting selected as [tokens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis#Token), you will come to know that primitives are the only datatypes that a compiler knows by itself.